# MySQL - Select Field With Nested 'WHERE'

Tags: mysql, nested, where-clause

I'm working on a project which uses the SUM command to get a number of values. Now, all of this works fine but there is an issue when it comes to load time as the query takes 3.4 seconds to complete.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
SELECT
p.`player_id`,
p.`player_name` AS `name`,
d.`player_debut` AS `debut`,
SUM(a.`player_order` <= '11' OR a.`player_sub` != '0') AS `apps`,
SUM(a.`player_order` <= '11') AS `starts`,
SUM(a.`player_goals`) AS `goals`
FROM
`table1` r,
`table2` a,
`table3` p
LEFT JOIN `table4` d ON p.`player_id` = d.`player_id`
WHERE
r.`match_id` = a.`match_id` AND
a.`player_id` = p.`player_id` AND
r.`void` = '0'
GROUP BY
a.`player_id`
ORDER BY
p.`player_name` ASC
```

Cast your mind to line 4. That field is retrieved by making use of the LEFT JOIN further down the query. By taking those two lines out, load time decreases to less than 0.5 seconds - a significant improvement.

What I'm trying to achieve there (line 4), without success, is something similar to lines 5-7, where a sort of invisible WHERE clause has been applied.

The idea would be `t4.date WHERE t2.order <= '14'`, but I'm not sure how I'd be able to get this to work without the aforementioned LEFT JOIN and increased load time that comes with it.

For clarification, here is how `table4` was created - with the following query turned into a VIEW.

```
SELECT a.`player_id`, m.`date` AS `player_debut`
FROM
`table1` r,
`table2` a,
`table3` p
WHERE
a.`match_id` = m.`match_id` AND
a.`player_id` = p.`player_id` AND
m.`match_void` = '0' AND
(
    a.`player_order` BETWEEN '1' AND '11' OR
    a.`player_sub_on_for` != '0'
)
GROUP BY p.`player_id`
ORDER BY p.`player_name` ASC
```

Essentially, as I am making use of the same tables for both queries and only utilising a different WHERE clause, I'm trying to establish if there is a way to 'nest' this.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If the information is in `table4` you need to have this table in the `FROM` clause (or by means of a subquery, that would be treated, most probably, in exactly the same manner by the planner/executor of the DBMS). That is, you cannot avoid any of this. You need to make sure that the appropriate `indices` are in place... but that's about the best you can do.

Comment: Try to create Database Indexes for each field.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: Would you like to provide sample data. Also there is no table aliased with m in your view should this be r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need conditional aggregation

```
SELECT p.`player_id`, p.`player_name` AS `name`, 
min(case when a.player_order   <= '11' OR a.`player_sub` != '0' then r.date else  0 end) `debut`,
SUM(case when a.`player_order` <= '11' OR a.`player_sub` != '0' then 1 else  0 end) AS `apps`,
SUM(case when a.`player_order` <= '11' then 1 else 0 end) AS `starts`,
SUM(a.`player_goals`) AS `goals`
FROM
`table1` r,
left join `table2` a on r.`match_id` = a.`match_id`,
left join `table3` p on a.`player_id` = p.`player_id`
WHERE  r.`void` = '0'
GROUP BY p.player_id,a.`player_id`
ORDER BY p.player_id,p.`player_name`;
```

There seem to be some inconsistencies in your column names   ( a.`player_sub`,a.`player_sub_on_for`, m.`match_void`, r.`void` = '0') so I may not have got this quite right , and group by clause without aggregation is pointless.

Comment: Fantastic. Everything from my original query has remained the same, but I can now replace line 4 from my code with an alternative version of line 2 that you provided.

Instead of IF ELSE, I have used the following to ensure the CASE statement continues to loop until requirements are met.

`{MIN(CASE WHEN a.player_order <= '11' OR a.player_sub != '0' THEN r.date END) debut}`

Comment: Using the MIN command also allows me to remove the LEFT JOIN which was the main thing slowing the query down. We're now down from 3.4 seconds to less than 0.3 seconds.